# How to manage translations when a site is being re-installed frequently?

Tags: i18n-l10n

Sites built on a [profile](http://drupal.org/node/1006620), will, during it's early development experience frequent re-installs.

If a translator makes changes to a site, these will get lost when the database is dropped.

What options are there for handling this, in a way that survives re-installs?

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I don't do a lot of multilingual (hence the comment rather than a potentially useless answer), but are [these](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!includes!locale.inc/group/locale-api-import-export/7) of any use to you?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to make a copy of the translation options.

I'm not sure if a hook_cron or a drush can donwload the files, if not the only way is to donwload and them copy into 
../profiles/myprofile/translations/*.po